# file explorer is not getting open to upload a file

Tags: java, selenium, filepath

This is my HTML:

```
<button ng-if="!isIE()" id="UploadedFileBtn" data-ng-click="SelectFile()" title="Browse" text="Browse" style="padding-bottom :5px" class="ng-scope">
                        <mosaic-icon name="upload" width="20" height="20" class=""><svg class="icon" width="20" height="20"><use xlink:href="#mosaic_icon_upload"></use></svg></mosaic-icon>
                    </button>
```

One button is used to open file explorer.
This is my java code:

```
  public void depositSingleDocument(String path, String doctype) throws InterruptedException
    {
        DriverOperations.getWhenElementVisible(upload);
        upload.sendKeys(path);
```

i am not able to open the file explorer and hence can not pass the file path.

Comment: Shouldn't you actually click on the button? Something like DriverOperations.getWhenElementVisible(upload).click()?

Comment: yes, i just tried that too, now its getting open but can not pass the path and select the file

Comment: Normally it's `input` element who is accepting the upload path, not `button` element.
Can you provide the link to the page you are working on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, make sure the filepath has not caused an issue. Example path below:

```
E:\\Patients_Data\\Patient_One.xml

instead of E://Patients_Data/Patient_One.xml
```

Next,

If you have one more input tag along with button tag(i.e a textbox in the UI next to the button), then try calling sendkeys method for the input tag to set the file path.

If the above two points doesn't solve your problem, Then you have to go with below approach:
Click on a button which opens the file upload window, which is not a web component and not supported by Selenium. Use any third party tool like Autoit, Sikuli which supports native window popup

```
public void depositSingleDocument(String path, String doctype) throws InterruptedException
   {
       DriverOperations.getWhenElementVisible(upload);
       upload.click();
```

Comment: i tried with AutoIt, it worked. there is no any text box or input element.. direct button click and file explorer is opening.

Comment: yeah thats right.. not all the uploads work with sendkeys.. Sendkeys can be used if the upload has a textbox(input tag) with it. So using third party tool like Autoit, Sikuli are only way.